# Problems with GKE log-based custom metric HPA

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm working with a GKE cluster, my application has some 'special' logs that are used by a log-based metric as a simple 'counter' metric. I can see this metric in 'Metric Explorer' with name:

"logging.googleapis.com/user/custom_metric_name"

I'm trying to define an HPA for my application following:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics

using this metric. I tried running all commands listed in the guide and adding this piece of code:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: dployment-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: deployment-name
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: logging.googleapis.com|user|custom_metric_name
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 20
```

but the metric still does not work, using `kubectl get hpa` the target has **unknown**
and using `kubectl describe hpa` I get the following error:
"the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metric logging.googleapis.com|user|custom_metric_name: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: googleapi: Error 400: The supplied filter does not specify a valid combination of metric monitored resource descriptors. The query will not return any timme series., badRequest"

Anyone has some ideas? Thank for the help.

Comment: did you deploy metrics adapter ? any error inside that ?

Comment: @HarshManvar I deployed metric adapter it seems running well, is there a way to check more in detail?

Comment: @HarshManvar looking to the logs of the metric adapter I'm getting this error: "apiserver was unable to close cleanly the response writer: http2: stream closed" and "timeout or abort while handling: method=GET URI="/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta2"